# "RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding" in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption

In my application I want to send the public key encrypted password to the server. In android we used "RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding". Which padding can I used to achieve the same result in iOS? I tried with kSecPaddingPKCS1 , kSecPaddingOAEP and kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA1 but server failed to decrypt the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSString *)encryptRSA:(NSString *)plainTextString key:(SecKeyRef)publicKey
{
    size_t cipherBufferSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey);
    uint8_t *cipherBuffer = malloc(cipherBufferSize);
    uint8_t *nonce = (uint8_t *)[plainTextString UTF8String];

    SecKeyEncrypt(publicKey,
                  kSecPaddingOAEP,
                  nonce,
                  strlen( (char*)nonce ),
                  &cipherBuffer[0],
                  &cipherBufferSize);

    NSData *encryptedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:cipherBuffer length:cipherBufferSize];
    return [encryptedData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
}

-(NSString *)decryptRSA:(NSString *)cipherString key:(SecKeyRef)privateKey {
    size_t plainBufferSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(privateKey);
    uint8_t *plainBuffer = malloc(plainBufferSize);
    NSData *incomingData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:cipherString options:0];

    uint8_t *cipherBuffer = (uint8_t*)[incomingData bytes];
    size_t cipherBufferSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(privateKey);
    SecKeyDecrypt(privateKey,
                  kSecPaddingOAEP,
                  cipherBuffer,
                  cipherBufferSize,
                  plainBuffer,
                  &plainBufferSize);

    NSData *decryptedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:plainBuffer length:plainBufferSize];
    NSString *decryptedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; return decryptedString;
}
```

Source: https://launchkey.com/docs/api/encryption/objective-c/commoncrypto

Comment: Why are you calling the plaintext `nonce`?

Comment: I just use the code from launchkey.com and it works for me, don't know why then name id nonce.